# Kube MQ java Language

Tags: message-queuing

Can someone tell what's the highest version of gradle and java the KubeMQ java SDK supports?

As there are many function in the SDK directly or indirectly which creates issues related to the version of gradle, as it was created from the Gradle version 4.8 but the current gradle version is 7.5 so there'll be problems afterwards. so I wanted to know the highest versions which support it without changing the inner functions. Changing the build file can be tolerated though.

Just for reference, I am using the docker version of Kube MQ to finally connect the application.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

KubeMQ-SDK-Java works with JDK 8+

A Java version between 8 and 18 is required to execute Gradle. Java 19 and later versions are not yet supported.

Comment: Yes but like kubeMQ sdk has 4.8 gradle version, so when I run with gradle latest or 2-3 versions earlier it still outputs an error of indirect functions not working.

Comment: I mean it doesn't work with java version "18.0.2.1" 2022-08-18 and gradle version 7.5. I mean I changed the build file's dependencies from compile to implementation before compiling. but it throws some error which points to internal functions of java SDk.

Comment: could you look into this?

Comment: Add error to your question.